# Resize div like desktop application

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I'm looking for a way to be able to resize div like you would resize a component on a desktop app. I know about the `resize` CSS property, but you have to put your cursor on the bottom right corner to resize the element. What I mean by "like on a desktop app" is that I would be able to resize an element by moving my cursor anywhere on the border of it, not just on the bottom right corner.

I couldn't find any JS library or CSS property to do that, I know google drive has this functionnality (see screen)

[image]

Is there any way to achieve that easily ?

Comment: Hi @Carl did you able to get it working.i have a requirement in my project like this.pls give some input on this. So it would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

you can use `resize: both;`
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_resize)